# Using variable in a LIMIT clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, limit, clause, variables

I am writing a stored procedure where I have an input parameter called *my_size* that is an *INTEGER*. I want to be able to use it in a `LIMIT` clause in a `SELECT` statement. Apparently this is not supported, is there a way to work around this?

```
# I want something like:
SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT my_size;

# Instead of hardcoding a permanent limit:
SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: If you have control over which version of MySQL you use, it looks like this is fixed starting in v5.5.6. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918

Comment: found another simple solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/4315661

Comment: Note that in *MySQL 5.7.16* (and maybe others) the `LIMIT @nrows OFFSET @noffset` in a stored routine seems to be rejected too, while a `LIMIT nrows OFFSET noffset` is accepted, as long as you `DECLARE nrows INT; DECLARE noffset INT` at the routine's begining.

Comment: @Xenos
It didnt work in big query, do you know how to make it work in big query

Comment: @VarunKumar Share your query in a dedicated question if you need help, as I don't see any reason why this would not work for "big" query

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A search turned up [this article](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8094).  I've pasted the relevant text below.

> Here's a forum post showing an example of prepared statements letting
>   you assign a variable value to the limit clause:
>
> http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,126379,133966#msg-133966
>
> However, I think this bug should get some attention because I can't
>   imagine that prepared statements within a procedure will allow for any
>   procedure-compile-time optimizations.  I have a feeling that prepared
>   statements are compiled and executed at the runtime of the procedure,
>   which probaby has a negative impact on efficiency.  If the limit
>   clause could accept normal procedure variables (say, a procedure
>   argument), then the database could still perform compile-time
>   optimizations on the rest of the query, within the procedure.  This
>   would likely yield faster execution of the procedure.  I'm no expert
>   though.

Answer (score 33):

For those, who cannot use MySQL 5.5.6+ and don't want to write a stored procedure, there is another variant. We can add where clause on a subselect with ROWNUM.

```
SET @limit = 10;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT instances.*, 
         @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM instances, 
         (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
) d WHERE rank < @limit;
```

Answer (score 17):

**STORED PROCEDURE**

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE get_users(page_from INT, page_size INT)
BEGIN
  SET @_page_from = page_from;
  SET @_page_size = page_size;
  PREPARE stmt FROM "select u.user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname from users u limit ?, ?;";
  EXECUTE stmt USING @_page_from, @_page_size;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$

DELIMITER ;
```

**USAGE**

In the following example it retrieves 10 records each time by providing start as 1 and 11. 1 and 11 could be your page number received as GET/POST parameter from pagination.

```
call get_users(1, 10);
call get_users(11, 10);
```

Answer (score 16):

I know this answer has come late, but try SQL_SELECT_LIMIT.

Example:

```
Declare rowCount int;
Set rowCount = 100;
Set SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = rowCount;
Select blah blah
Set SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = Default;
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't seem to support an argument for starting position, like 5,2 for taking 2 rows from position 5. But unless you need that it may do the trick.

Comment: Also unfortunately this trick doesn't work for a `SELECT ...` part of queries such as `REPLACE ... SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 12):

This feature has been added to MySQL 5.5.6.
Check this [link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918) out.

I've upgraded to MySQL 5.5 just for this feature and works great.
5.5 also has a lot of performance upgrades in place and I totally recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, the same as wrote "Pradeep Sanjaya", but using CONCAT:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `some_func`(startIndex INT, countNum INT)
READS SQL DATA
  COMMENT 'example'
BEGIN
  SET @asd = CONCAT('SELECT `id` FROM `table` LIMIT ',startIndex,',',countNum);
  PREPARE zxc FROM @asd;
  EXECUTE zxc;
END;
```

Comment: It is great solution with using **`PREPARE`** and **`EXECUTE`** statement. One important note : we don't need to use Create procedure. We can use **`PREPARE`**and **`EXECUTE`** statement  in major code sql too.

Answer (score 1):

As of MySQL version 5.5.6, you can specify **`LIMIT`** and **`OFFSET`** with variables / parameters.

For reference, see the [5.5 Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#idm140195666212032), the [5.6 Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html#idm140462371147952) and @Quassnoi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2875365/506879)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem using MySql 5.0 and wrote a procedure with the help of @ENargit's answer:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SOME_PROCEDURE_NAME(IN _length INT, IN _start INT)
BEGIN
    SET _start = (SELECT COALESCE(_start, 0));
    SET _length = (SELECT COALESCE(_length, 999999)); -- USING ~0 GIVES OUT OF RANGE ERROR
    SET @row_num_personalized_variable = 0;

    SELECT
    *,
    @row_num_personalized_variable AS records_total         
    FROM(
        SELECT
        *,
        (@row_num_personalized_variable := @row_num_personalized_variable + 1) AS row_num
        FROM some_table
    ) tb
    WHERE row_num > _start AND row_num <= (_start + _length);
END;
```

Also included the total rows obtained by the query with records_total.

Answer (score 0):

you must DECLARE a variable and after that set it. then the LIMIt will work and put it in a StoredProcedure not sure if it works in normal query

like this:

```
DECLARE rowsNr INT DEFAULT 0;  
SET rowsNr = 15;  
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ... LIMIT rowsNr;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that many people here want to use LIMIT as a parameter without stored procedures.

it can be done with PREPARE and EXECUTE like this:

```
set @my_size = 100;
set @sql = concat("SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT ", @my_size);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```