# Stored procedure, using variable in LIMIT expression

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, limit

I have a stored procedure in which if I write the following query without a variable, all: works well

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `some_proc` ()
 BEGIN
 SELECT blabla FROM  mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 3,1
 .....
```

but, if I use a variable as start number in LIMIT expression, I get an error:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `some_proc` ()
 BEGIN
 DECLARE start INT;
 SET start = 3;
 SELECT blabla FROM  mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT start,1
 .....
```

Is there a way to use a variable in the LIMIT expression inside the stored procedure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing LIMIT as parameters to MySQL sproc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875238/passing-limit-as-parameters-to-mysql-sproc)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot use a variable directly. A nice workaround that I've seen is -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `some_proc` (
IN _START INTEGER, 
IN _LIMIT INTEGER 
)
BEGIN 
PREPARE STMT FROM 
" SELECT * FROM products LIMIT ?,? "; 
SET @START = _START; 
SET @LIMIT = _LIMIT; 
EXECUTE STMT USING @START, @LIMIT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
END $$
```

Another search returned this - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8094.

Also you can read more about prepared statements in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in MySQL 5.5 - [SELECT statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

From the documentation:

> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
>   integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL
>   5.5.6.