# MySql stored procedure with limit parameters gives err.no : 1064 when we use CONCAT statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

We have a long sql procedure that takes limit & amount(limitCount) parameters. So, we are using concat statement for joining multiple queries. Calling this procedure gives err.no 1064 when we try to run it.

EDIT : Based on the comment, I'm adding the whole code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getProfileTasks  (IN p_id1 INT, IN p_id2 INT , IN limitStart INT, IN limitCount INT)
BEGIN

SET @SQL = CONCAT('
       SELECT P.access_type INTO @privacy FROM Profile P WHERE P.profile_id = ' , p_id2 , ';
 IF( ' , p_id1, ' = ' ,p_id2 , ')
 THEN

 SELECT T.task_id, T.name, D.add_time, D.location, DATE_FORMAT(D.date1, "%d/%m/%y") as `date1`, D.time3, D.state, TIME_FORMAT(D.time1, "%H:%i")as `time1`, D.does_id, IFNULL(L.Like, 0) AS `LikeCount` , IFNULL(C.CommentCount,0) AS `CommentCount` FROM Task T
       INNER JOIN Does D on D.task_id = T.task_id
       INNER JOIN Profile P on P.profile_id = D.profile_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                               SELECT D.does_id, COUNT(L.profile_id) as `Like` FROM `Likes` L
                               INNER JOIN Does D on D.does_id = L.does_id
                               INNER JOIN Profile P on P.profile_id = D.profile_id
                               WHERE P.profile_id = ' ,  p_id2 , '
                               GROUP BY does_id) L on L.does_id = D.does_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN( SELECT D.does_id, COUNT(C.content) AS `CommentCount` FROM Comment C
                               INNER JOIN Does D on D.does_id = C.does_id
                               GROUP BY (D.does_id)) C ON C.does_id = D.does_id
       WHERE P.profile_id= ' , p_id2, ' ORDER BY D.add_time DESC LIMIT ' , limitStart , ', ' , limitCount,  ';
 ELSE

       IF (@privacy = 0)

       THEN

                  SELECT T.task_id, T.name, D.add_time, D.location, DATE_FORMAT(D.date1, "%d/%m/%y") as `date1`, D.time3, D.state, TIME_FORMAT(D.time1, "%H:%i")as `time1`,  D.does_id, IFNULL(L.Like,0) AS `LikeCount`, IFNULL(C.CommentCount,0) AS `CommentCount`  FROM Task T
                  INNER JOIN Does D on D.task_id = T.task_id
                  INNER JOIN Profile P on P.profile_id = D.profile_id
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                               SELECT D.does_id, COUNT(L.profile_id) as `Like` FROM `Likes` L
                               INNER JOIN Does D on D.does_id = L.does_id
                               INNER JOIN Profile P on P.profile_id = D.profile_id
                               WHERE P.profile_id = ' ,  p_id2 , '
                               GROUP BY does_id) L on L.does_id = D.does_id
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN( SELECT D.does_id, COUNT(C.content) AS `CommentCount` FROM Comment C
                               INNER JOIN Does D on D.does_id = C.does_id
                               GROUP BY (D.does_id) )C ON C.does_id = D.does_id
                  WHERE P.profile_id= ' ,p_id2, ' ORDER BY D.add_time DESC LIMIT ' , limitStart , ', ' , limitCount,  ';
       ELSE

                  IF EXISTS ( SELECT *  FROM Follows F
                  INNER JOIN Profile P on F.follower_id = P.profile_id
                  INNER JOIN Profile P2 on F.following_id = P2.profile_id
                  WHERE (P.profile_id = ' ,  p_id1, '  AND P2.profile_id = ' ,  p_id2 , '))
                  THEN
                           SELECT T.task_id, T.name, D.add_time, D.location, DATE_FORMAT(D.date1, "%d/%m/%y") as `date1`, D.time3, D.state, TIME_FORMAT(D.time1, "%H:%i")as `time1`, D.does_id, IFNULL(L.Like,0) AS `LikeCount`, IFNULL(C.CommentCount,0) AS `CommentCount` FROM Task T
                           INNER JOIN Does D on D.task_id = T.task_id
                           INNER JOIN Profile P on P.profile_id = D.profile_id
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                               SELECT D.does_id, COUNT(L.profile_id) as `Like` FROM `Likes` L
                               INNER JOIN Does D on D.does_id = L.does_id
                               INNER JOIN Profile P on P.profile_id = D.profile_id
                               WHERE P.profile_id = ' ,  p_id2 , '
                               GROUP BY does_id) L on L.does_id = D.does_id
                           LEFT OUTER JOIN( SELECT D.does_id, COUNT(C.content) AS `CommentCount` FROM Comment C
                               INNER JOIN Does D on D.does_id = C.does_id
                               GROUP BY (D.does_id) )C ON C.does_id = D.does_id
                           WHERE P.profile_id= ' , p_id2 , ' ORDER BY D.add_time DESC LIMIT ' , limitStart , ', ' , limitCount,  ';

                   END IF;

        END IF;
 END IF; '
);

PREPARE query FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE query;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;

END
```

Anyone has any idea about why we are getting this error ?

```
ERROR : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF( 18 = 18) THEN SELECT T.task_id, T.name, D.add_time, D.location, DATE_' at line 2
```

P.S : DELIMITER is set to //

Comment: What exact error? It will probably specify a line or character where the error starts.

Comment: I've added the exact error. @Michael

Comment: Would be helpful to post full query without the blah-blahs, however my guess is you are using a reserved word in your query.  Maybe Like?

Comment: Allright. I'm editing it right now.

Comment: @Gary query works itself without adding limit and parameters feature. So, I don't think that 'Like' makes the problem.

Comment: Does `EXECUTE` support multiple delimited statements? I never tried it, and it isn't mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @Michael We have another stored procedure with 1 long select statement, execute works correctly in that stored procedure

Comment: @Michael any alternative to EXECUTE ?

Comment: Although I'm not very familiar with stored procedures, it just doesn't make sense to me that you would create a string, use that to create a prepared statement, execute it without parameters (because they are already used in the string) and then drop the prepared statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since the way the query in the stored procedure was created isn't really server-friendly (nor friendly to other developers) I have reformatted the stored procedure. Then I also noted that it's actually the same query that's executed in three cases, so there is a lot of duplication.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getProfileTasks  (IN p_id1 INT, IN p_id2 INT , IN limitStart INT, IN limitCount INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE privacy INT;
    DECLARE is_following INT;

    SELECT P.access_type INTO privacy FROM Profile P WHERE P.profile_id = p_id2;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO is_following
    FROM Follows F
    INNER JOIN Profile P on F.follower_id = P.profile_id
    INNER JOIN Profile P2 on F.following_id = P2.profile_id
    WHERE (P.profile_id = p_id1 AND P2.profile_id = p_id2)
    LIMIT 1;

    IF ( (p_id1 = p_id2) OR (privacy = 0) OR (is_following > 0) )
    THEN

        -- Using CONCAT and prepared statement because LIMIT won't work otherwise
        @SQL = CONCAT('
            SELECT
                  T.task_id
                , T.name
                , D.add_time
                , D.location
                , DATE_FORMAT(D.date1, "%d/%m/%y") AS `date1`
                , D.time3
                , D.state
                , TIME_FORMAT(D.time1, "%H:%i") AS `time1`
                , D.does_id
                , IFNULL(L.`Like`, 0) AS `LikeCount`
                , IFNULL(C.CommentCount,0) AS `CommentCount`
            FROM Task T
            INNER JOIN Does D on D.task_id = T.task_id
            INNER JOIN Profile P on P.profile_id = D.profile_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT D.does_id, COUNT(L.profile_id) AS `Like`
                FROM `Likes` L
                INNER JOIN Does D on D.does_id = L.does_id
                INNER JOIN Profile P on P.profile_id = D.profile_id
                WHERE P.profile_id = @p_id2
                GROUP BY does_id
            ) L on L.does_id = D.does_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT D.does_id, COUNT(C.content) AS `CommentCount`
                FROM Comment C
                INNER JOIN Does D on D.does_id = C.does_id
                GROUP BY (D.does_id)
            ) C ON C.does_id = D.does_id
            WHERE P.profile_id= @p_id2
            ORDER BY D.add_time DESC
            LIMIT  ', limitStart, ', ' , limitCount, ';');

        SET @p_id2 = p_id2;

        PREPARE query FROM @SQL;
        EXECUTE query USING @p_id2;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;

    END IF;

END
```

And I also added backticks around `Like` in `` IFNULL(L.`Like`, 0) AS `LikeCount` ``, because that's a potential problem as pointed out in the comments of the question.

Comment: mysql doesn't accept limit value as parameter. That's why we use concat operation in creating procedure. but it seems easier to read & understand. let me try converting this query in concat format and try it again

Comment: the problem still exists even if we use concat for this query

Comment: And what happens if you don't use concat and also don't use the limit clause? It should at least give you an indication where the problem is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315619/mysql-stored-procedure-using-declared-vars-in-a-limit-statement-returns-an-erro it gives syntax error like here

Comment: That's with the limit clause, but what happens if you remove the limit clause from the query? First get it to work without the limit clause (so the sql statement is correct), then look for a way to add the limit clause (like described in that question).

Comment: that concat operation works when there are not multiple queries inside the stored procedure. however, if we try to concat limit with multiple queries, then it won't work.

Comment: So you should get a prepared statement with just one query. See my updated answer for that.

Comment: it gives this error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@SQL = CONCAT(' SELECT T.task_id ,' at line 20