# SQL limit result to top 50%

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried two methods but failed in mysql.

```
/*see top 50% students, but this sql can't work*/
select * from student_table order by chinese_score desc limit count(*) * 0.5 ;

/*also can't work*/
set @num= floor((select count(*) from test.student_score)*0.5);
select * from student_table order by chinese_score desc limit @num ;
```

How to solve in mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195430/variable-in-mysql-limit

Comment: @etsa , Actually I run sqls in Hive, which doesn't support `PROCEDURE`.

Comment: Why did you tagged it with MySQL?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz , I also wonder the answer without PROCEDURE on mysql occasion.  ;-)

Comment: Each DB has its own solution. Don't mix the questions.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz , I saw your sqlserver edition post. I trust it's okay and u needn't have deleted it.

Comment: It's Hive (although it works for every DB that supports windows functions). As I said, the questions should not be mixed. I've removed the Hive tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ***Mysql*** this can be done in a single query using [user defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

> You can store a value in a user-defined variable in one statement and
>   refer to it later in another statement. This enables you to pass
>   values from one statement to another.

```
SELECT * FROM    (
          SELECT student_table.*, @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
          FROM (SELECT @counter:=0) AS initvar, student_table
          ORDER BY student_table.chinese_score DESC
        ) AS result
WHERE counter < (@counter/2) ORDER BY chinese_score DESC;
```