# How to use the result of a select as offset in an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, offset

I was trying to create a single SQL query to return what I need, instead of creating 2 querys, but I need to use the result of one of the querys as the `offset` of the other one.

My table has user answers with scores, each user may have multiple answers in that table. And I want to calculate the middle point of the table of ordered scores.

Example:

**User answers:**

1. User 1 - 5 points
2. User 1 - 15 points
3. User 2 - 8 points
4. User 3 - 12 points

**Ranking Table:**

1. User 1 - 20 points
2. User 3 - 12 points **< Middle point**
3. User 2 - 8 points

---

**Solution:**

The first query calculates the middle point:

```
SELECT CEILING(count(Distinct(id_user)) / 2) as position 
FROM us_user_response 
where id_round=1
```

Query result:

> position : 2

This second query creates the ordered ranking table:

```
SELECT sum(points) as score 
FROM us_user_response 
where id_round=1 
GROUP BY id_user 
Order by score DESC
```

Now I want to create one big query that returns the score of the middle user, I just need to use the first query result as `offset` of the second query:

```
SELECT sum(points) as score 
      FROM us_user_response 
      where id_round=1
      GROUP BY id_user 
      Order by score DESC LIMIT 1
        OFFSET (SELECT CEILING(count(Distinct(id_user)) / 2) as position 
                FROM us_user_response where id_round=1)
```

Of course, this doesn't work, is there any way to use a result as `offset`?

---

**EDIT:**

The queries work nice! My question is if there is any way to use the result of a query as the offset of another. So I could accomplish this in one single query.

Comment: Can't you also select their user id, then use that?

Comment: I need the middle score ... the only way to get that is to get the middle element of the ordered table ...

Comment: The querys work just fine! I just wanted to take the two querys and create only one. By using the first as the offset of the second query.

Comment: Why are you using `id_round=214` in the main query, but `id_round=1` in the position query? It think it should work correctly if they both query the same round.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about the 214 value, copy past typo.

Comment: Why doesn't the combined query you wrote work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, the combined query doesn't work: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; `

Comment: Prior to MySQL 5.5.6, you can't calculate the values in a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable LIMIT Clause in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: Ok, thanks @Barmar, although I cannot update my mysql :) I didn't searched for limit as result of query ... If you want so, provide your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I don't feel the need to answer a duplicate, I expect it will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SET @line_id = 0;
SET @line_offset = (
    SELECT CEILING(count(Distinct(id_user)) / 2) as position 
    FROM us_user_response 
    WHERE id_round = 1
);

SELECT sum(points) as score,
    IF((@line_id := @line_id + 1) = @line_offset, 1, 0) AS useit 
FROM us_user_response 
WHERE id_round = 1
GROUP BY id_user 
HAVING useit = 1
ORDER BY score;
```