# MySQL: Can you specify a random limit?

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-limit

Is there a way to randomize a limit number in SQL (MySQL)?

What I'd like to be able to do is get a random number of results in a query to use in an insertion subquery without any server-side scripting.  The query I'd love to be able to run as a hypothetical illustration is:

```
SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT RAND() * 1000
```

Of course that doesn't work, but is there another way to randomize the limit number?  There are plenty of examples of randomizing a limited set of results, but I can't find anything on the net about setting a random limit.

Comment: good one .. I when I had same issue i used `order by Rand() limit 10`

Comment: If you are using an application to call MySQL, you could easily randomize the value in the application.

Comment: Check answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql

Comment: I need to use the results in a subquery so setting variables and so on won't work (at least I don't think it won't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM users
     ORDER BY RAND()
     HAVING RAND() * 1000 < 10
```

The clause `WHERE RAND() * 1000 < 10` randomly chooses to include each row with a probability of 1%. It's not quite a `LIMIT variable` clause but will do roughly the same thing.

Comment: This was nice!  I had to reformat it a little bit, but the idea was tasty and simple!

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE RAND() * 1000 < 10 ORDER BY RAND();`

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL specifically:

```
SET @i = 0;
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE (@i:=@i+1) < RAND()*1000
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: Doesn't work. 

I'd like to accomplish this in a single query without any variables though.

Comment: Yep, that works nice too!  It's not a single query so the winning answer suited my needs better, but this is still a good solution.  Thanks!