# MySQL - Load Data Infile with variable path

Tags: mysql, variables, path

I'm having a problem with setting a variable path for putting data into my table.
This is how i build my path:

```
SET @path1 = CONCAT('C:/Projekte/Metrics/DXL_CSV_EXPORT_DATA/', YEAR(NOW()), '_',    MONTH(NOW()), '_', DAY(NOW()), '%', '/_','BeMiko/');`
```

Every day another Folder is created on the server. I want to automatically import the information from the .csv files from inside these folders each day.

I import data from files with:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
path...
IGNORE INTO TABLE table1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '<*line_end*>\r\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

How do i use the string inside my @path1 variable as path?
Or if this is not possible: Are there other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: You should be able to generate the SQL statement on-the-fly. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10025538/1446005).

Comment: This could work, but somehow i always get an error if i try to execute the procedure. The error says: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet (Error Code 1295). How can i fix this?

Comment: Oops. Then I don't know. Do you have shell access? Then you could `mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE $var ..."`

Comment: Working in a shell isn't what i should do right now. I need to create a procedure, which gets executed once a day (event..).

Answer (score 2):

Variables can't be used to substitute paths in the LOAD DATA INFILE statement.

Also:

> User variables may be used in most contexts where expressions are permitted. This does not currently include contexts that explicitly require a literal value, such as in the LIMIT clause of a SELECT statement, or the IGNORE N LINES clause of a LOAD DATA statement.

- as seen in the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)