# Procedure, Import different files to different tables, fixed width

Tags: mysql, import

I saw this post [MySQL load data: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360756/mysql-load-data-this-command-is-not-supported-in-the-prepared-statement-protoco) and didn't get it quite right so i'm posting my own code.

I've got monthly tables starting in 200601 and i need to import fixed width text files into them (these are also monthly, i.e, 200601.txt; 200602.txt; ...; 201710.txt).

```
BEGIN

DECLARE count INT Default 200600;
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET @a := count + 1;
         SET @statement = CONCAT('
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

','"D:/path/2006/',@a,'.txt"','

INTO TABLE 

database.',@a,'

(@ROW)
SET proc = trim(substr(@row,1,6)),
product = trim(substr(@row,7,4)),
subp = trim(substr(@row,11,4)),
cont = trim(substr(@row,15,20)),
client = trim(substr(@row,35,8)),
sis = trim(substr(@row,43,3)),
#[and a lot more]
');
         PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;
                 EXECUTE stmt;
                 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
                 SET count = count + 1;
         IF count=200612 THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
END LOOP simple_loop;

END
```

Then I get

```
Error Code: 1295. This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet.
```

at the line

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

Is there any way around that? A software maybe?

Comment: Can you indicate the line of code that throws the error?

Comment: It's the LOCAL DATA command.