# MySql Query Limit based on Sub Query Value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, logic

I am looking for a solution to use sub query in limit value.

Ex:

```
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE usertype='6' LIMIT
  (SELECT count(*) FROM allowed WHERE usertype='6')
```

Is there any other way to use a sub Query in LIMIT. I tried the above Query but Its not working.

Comment: Do it in 2 steps: 1. select the limit from the 1-st table, 2. use it in the 2-nd query

Comment: I need it to be in single query is that possible. I can do that by two different queries..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable LIMIT Clause in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: do you have user_id in allowed table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with MySql; you have to use a stored procedure/prepared statement as workaround.

Lots of people have requested this:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8094

but as you see from the bug listing, this is still open.

**EDIT**: actually, it seems to have been added in version 5.5.6:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918