# MySQL limit with variable

Tags: mysql, variables, limit

I have an error in my syntax :

```
SET @start := 0;
SELECT (ROUND((count(item))/2)) FROM car INTO @until; 

SELECT * FROM car
LIMIT @until OFFSET @start;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@until OFFSET @start' at line 1

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a [*user-defined*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) variable (`@until`) in the `LIMIT` clause.

A possible solution (a variation on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17059426/1005334)):

```
SELECT (ROUND((count(item))/2)) FROM car INTO @until;
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, 
         @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
    FROM car, 
         (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
) d WHERE rank < @until;
```

Only downside is you lose the offset, but you can accommodate that by adjusting the `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, you can use a stored procedure.

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':= @until' at line 1

Comment: Scrap that, the problem is with your usage of the variable with `LIMIT`. It appears you can't use it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql. I'll update my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pagination(
    INT pageno INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE pages INT;
    DECLARE pagefrom INT;

    SET pages = 1000; -- get this many records at a time
    SET pagefrom = pageno * pages; -- 2 * 1000 = 2000

    SELECT *
    FROM car
    LIMIT pagefrom, pages;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL pagination(2);
```

This example will get records from 2000 to 3000

Comment: For those who didn't immediately see the point: instead of using a [_user-defined_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) variables, you can use the `DECLARE` syntax for defining [_local variables_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html). Local variables declared in such manner can be used with `LIMIT`. Just remember that `DECLARE` statements must be written first inside the body of a prepared statement.