# Trying to put a variable into limit to find a median

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, median

I trying to use mysql to solve the following solutions:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem

Understanding that a variable cannot be put into LIMIT statement (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033593/mysql-limit-with-variable) )

My approach>

to declare a new variable to record rowIDs, and use rowID to retrieve the record in the middle.
However, it seems that rowID is not working well. 
Could anyone give me some advises?

```
SELECT ROUND(COUNT(LAT_N)/2,0) FROM STATION into @count;
SELECT ROUND(a.LAT_N,4) FROM (
SELECT *,@row := @row + 1 FROM STATION s, (SELECT @row := 0) r
    WHERE @row <=@count
    ORDER BY s.LAT_N ASC) a
ORDER BY a.LAT_N DESC  LIMIT 1;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, this is simpler done with window functions:

```
select round(avg(lat_n), 4) median_lat_n
from (
    select s.*, row_number() over(orer by lat_n) rn
    from station s
    where lat_n is not null
) s
where rn * 2 in (rn - 1, rn, rn + 1)
```

In earlier versions, variables make it bit tricky; we need one more level of nesting to make it safe:

```
select round(avg(lat_n), 2) median_lat_n
from (
    select s.*, @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from (select * from station order by lat_n) s
    cross join (select @rn := 0) p
) s
where rn  * 2 in (rn - 1, rn, rn + 1)
```

The logic is as follows: first enumerate the rows, ordered by `lat_n`. If the row count is uneven, we pick the middle row; if it is even, we take the average of the two middle values.

Comment: Why it is safer to make one more level of nesting? Would you please share a little bit more 
 about that? 
>>    from (select s.* from station order by lat_n) s

Comment: @Hsin: variables and ordering are tricky; it is safer to order the resultset in a subquery, then use variables.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks!!