# mysql c api limit function

Tags: mysql, limit, c-api

```
mysql_query(conn,"SELECT abstract FROM papers limit 4 ");
```

Can we use variables in limit function in C-api.Like I have to iteratively extract 10 rows,so something of the form:
    mysql_query(conn,"SELECT abstract FROM papers limit $i $i+10 ");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable LIMIT Clause in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

what you seek is "OFFSET"

e.g. `SELECT abstract FROM papers LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20`
gives 10 results (skipping over the first 20)

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above issue by using strings.
        strcpy(query,"SELECT abstract from PAPERS limit ");
        pos=0;
        sprintf(temp,"%d %d",pos,pos+100);
        strcat(query,temp);

In this way pos can also be used as iterator.