# Variable in LIMIT Clause in MySQL 5.6.1 not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Per this [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql/17059426#17059426) it's my understanding that I could run a query like this in mysql version 5.5.6+:

```
set @limit_start=10;
set @limit_offset=10;
select
    ID,
    AGE, 
    GENDER
from
    PLAYER
limit
    @limit_start, @limit_offset;
```

But when I run it like so, I get an error.

```
mysql> set @limit_start=10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set @limit_offset=10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select
    ->     ID
    -> from
    ->     PLAYER_GAME_RESULT
    -> limit
    ->     @limit_start, @limit_offset;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@limit_start, @limit_offset' at line 6
```

This is me checking the mysql version

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.6.21    |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) is pretty clear.  In a *stored program*, then `limit` can take a variable/parameter as an argument:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
>   exceptions:
>
> - Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
> - Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.

Your code is not a stored program.  Hence, you need to use constants.