# How to show 10% of all the records using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show only 15% of all records using mysql, all I see is a way to show only a specific number of rows. Is there a way to do such thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to maintain a degree of consistency here. Ten? Fifteen?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to calculate it by yourself like

```
declare var int;    
select var = (count(*) * .15) from mytable;

select * from mytable
order by id
limit 1, var;
```

You can also use `SQL_SELECT_LIMIT` option like below. Got from this thread [Variable LIMIT Clause in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql)

```
Set SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = var;

select * from mytable
order by id;
```

Comment: replace `=` with `:=` ...

Comment: @stack, it's a declared variable and so not needed.

Comment: Ah I see ...... Just why `.15`? OP said `10%`

Comment: @stack, read the question again; it says *I want to show only 15% ...*