# PHP Pagination not working when Records Filter is applied

Tags: php, pagination

I have written a PHP script which has option to filter records and display filtered records pagewise.

**My Problem**:
When I apply the filter, the records are displayed but when I click on any page number it displays all records page wise instead of showing filtered records pagewise.

How can I correct this?
Here is my complete script,

```
    <body>
        <form style="background-color:darkorange; font-size: 13px;" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="displaydesign.php">
            <label>Design Category</label>
            <select name="dlocation">
            <option value="">All</option>
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY dlocation ORDER BY dlocation";
                $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
                    echo "<option value='".$row["dlocation"]."'".($row["dlocation"]==$_REQUEST["dlocation"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["dlocation"]."</option>";
                }
            ?>
            </select>

            <input type="text" name="string" id="string" value="<?php echo stripcslashes($_REQUEST["string"]); ?>" placeholder="Search by Name or City" />
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />

              <a style="background-color:white;" href="displaydesign.php"> Reset</a>
        </form>
        <hr>

        <?php
        if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
            $search_string = " AND (dname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR dcity LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')"; 
        }
        if ($_REQUEST["dlocation"]<>'') {
            $search_dlocation = " AND dlocation='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["dlocation"])."'";    
        }
        $per_page=2;    // no.of records per page
        if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
            $page = $_GET["page"];
        }
        else {
            $page=1;
        }
        // Page will start from 0 and Multiple by Per Page
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE did>0".$search_string.$search_dlocation." order by did desc LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) { ?>
                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="card" >
                        <h3 class="card-header card-success text-center"><?php echo $row['dlocation'] ?></h3>
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="<?php echo $row['dimage'] ?>" alt="Card image cap">
                        <div class="card-block ">
                            <h4><span class="badge badge-default">Designer Information</span></h4>
                            <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['dname'] ?></h5>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted "><?php echo ($row['dcity'])?></h6>
                            <p class="text-right">
                              <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                Know More..
                              </a>
                            </p>
                            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                <div class="card card-block">
                                    <h5><span class="badge badge-warning">Contact Info</span></h5>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><a href="mailto:<?php echo ($row['demail'])?>" target="_top"><?php echo ($row['demail'])?></a></h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><?php echo ($row['dmobile'])?></h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><?php echo ($row['daddress'])?></h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><?php echo ($row['dcity'])?></h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><a href="<?php echo ($row['dwebsite'])?>"><?php echo ($row['dwebsite'])?></a></h6>
                                    <!--ACCORDION START-->
                                    <div id="accordion<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                      <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                          <h5 class="mb-0 btn-sm">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" href="#collapseOne<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                              Image Description
                                            </a>
                                          </h5>
                                        </div>

                                        <div id="collapseOne<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                          <div class="card-block">
                                            <?php echo $row['dimagedescription'] ?>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                          <h5 class="mb-0 btn-sm">
                                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" href="#collapseTwo<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                              Software Used
                                            </a>
                                          </h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="collapseTwo<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                          <div class="card-block">
                                            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row['dsoftwareused'] ?></p>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                          <h5 class="mb-0 btn-sm">
                                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" href="#collapseThree<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                              My Brand Recommendation
                                            </a>
                                          </h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="collapseThree<?php echo ($row['did'])?>" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree<?php echo ($row['did'])?>">
                                          <div class="card-block">
                                            <div class="card">
                                              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                                <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $row['dbrandname'] ?></li>
                                                <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $row['dbrandsegment'] ?></li>
                                                <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $row['dbrandwebsite'] ?></li>
                                                <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $row['dbrandemail'] ?></li>
                                              </ul>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <!--ACCORDION END-->
                                </div>
                            </div>              
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <small class="text-muted">Design ID:- <?php echo stripcslashes($row['did']) ?> Submitted on :-<?php echo stripcslashes($row['dsubmissiondate']) ?></small>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                <?php } ?>
        </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
        <h3>No results found for the desired Search.</h3>
        <?php } ?>
            <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <div>
        <?php       //for page numbers display at bottom of page

        //Now select all from table for pagination 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE did>0".$search_string.$search_dlocation." order by did desc";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);

        // Count the total records
        $total_records = mysql_num_rows($sql_result);

        //Using ceil function to divide the total records on per page
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

        //Going to first page
        echo "<center><a href='displaydesign.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a> ";

        for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {

        echo "<a href='displaydesign.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
        };
        // Going to last page
        echo "<a href='displaydesign.php?page=$total_pages'>".'Last Page'."</a></center> ";
        ?>
        </div>
            </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking over your code, and I also setup an SQL-Fiddle (see below) to play around. I was initially thinking that maybe the MySQL query you use doesn't filter right on specific values or doesn't paginate right but filters right. Anyway there are also comments in the fiddle that explain some ideas and assumptions I made.

---

For what it's worth, pagination and complex SQL queries are non-trivial. They can also be expensive, and while I don't know your current code platform/setup/environment, I would suggest to push logic and things like pagination to the front end or JavaScript wherever possible. PHP works, too, but I'm mostly trying to point out that in my experience *complexity for SQL queries often increases more quickly than code because it's a different type of frameset, namely relational versus procedural*.

Your code also contains view and business logic together as well as SQL, so to be open with you I might not find the issue or there may be more than one. But I did notice some things looking at your code.

(1) The paginated results for your contacts list query were NOT exclusive by page number - meaning in some cases a row from a previous result would be included in the results.

(2) There is weird behavior if there are every any empty values for your WHERE conditions values -- specifically, $dname, $dcity, $dlocation. I didn't manage to reproduce your exact issue from JUST the SQL in the SQL fiddle, but I'm wondering if you'll see the same issues with some cleanup to the list query.

Fix Suggestions:

- Modify SQL query to use rank and an inner-query to exclusive-paginate results and eliminate empty-match issues. In my suggested query below and in the fiddle, I've adjusted the WHERE condition from *a AND (b or c) AND d* to *a AND ( (b or c) or d )* -- while this looks weird, it says "make sure we're matching on a non-empty location (assumed primary selector), or that we have a name or city to filter by". At least one variable must match true for the LIKE condition checks or it won't return a result row for it, whereas the other way required all three matches for a row (which is fine if those values will always be non-empty).

  ```
    SET @name = "";
    SET @city = "";
    SET @location = "WA";

    SET @per_page = 1;
    -- Setting this arbitrarily - looking at different pages
    -- mostly verifying yeah, the fetch/ pagination part works.
    SET @page = 3;
    SET @rownum = 0;
    -- Basic Fetch Query used for getting list-for-page
    SELECT
      results.id, results.name, 
      results.location, results.city,
      results.rank
    FROM (
      SELECT
        c.id AS id
        ,c.name AS name
        ,c.location AS location
        ,c.city AS city
        ,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
      FROM contacts AS c
      -- ,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      WHERE c.id > 0
        AND ( (c.name LIKE @name OR c.city LIKE @city)
        OR c.location LIKE @location )
      ORDER BY c.id ASC
    ) AS results
    WHERE rank BETWEEN ( (@page-1) * @per_page + 1) AND ( (@page) * @per_page )
  ```

---

### Clarification

There are 2 new things going on in this bigger query. One, there is something called an *"inner query"* being used to pre-select a set of rows. Second, I'm assigning a rank value to use in my final results query to organize the table rows into "paged" results. This is a workaround to trying to use

```
WHERE ...
LIMIT ((@page-1)*@per_page), @per_page
```

or even

```
WHERE ...
LIMIT ((@page-1)*@per_page) OFFSET @per_page
```

But (see my CREDITS section), apparently one CANNOT use @vars in SQL. You could also work around this in your code by using PHP string templating or something, like you're already doing to inject variables into strings.

---

### SQL Fiddle

Here's that SQL Fiddle to see what assumptions I made and what I was doing:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d516e/26

---

### Credits

Apparently, one cannot use user variables like @name in the LIMIT-clause, which I did not know before. I found another Stack post to help me with that problem:
[Using variable in a LIMIT clause in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql)