# How to replace the LIMIT clause in a mySQL query in a safe way with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to replace the LIMIT quantity in a mySQL query to a variable.

This does work:

```
$x = $conectarDB->prepare("
  SELECT contenidoID, titulo, fecha, encabezado
  FROM contenidos
  WHERE publicado = 1
  ORDER BY fecha DESC
  LIMIT ".$limit."
  ");
$x->execute();
$y = $x->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But this doesn't:

```
$x = $conectarDB->prepare("
  SELECT contenidoID, titulo, fecha, encabezado
  FROM contenidos
  WHERE publicado = 1
  ORDER BY fecha DESC
  LIMIT ?
  ");
$x->bindParam(1, $limit);
$x->execute();
$y = $x->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I receive this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2'' at line 5'
>   in /public_html/includes/footer-info-extra.php:25

How to change that number in a secure way? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Please note that I've been reading about [how to do that in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/variable-limit-clause-in-mysql), I want to do it in php

Comment: Just look up how bind_param actually works.
http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: You are using PDO it's slightly different then Mysqli.
In PDO there are few ways to achieve the same results. you can first try:

    $x = $conectarDB->prepare("
    SELECT contenidoID, titulo, fecha, encabezado
    FROM contenidos
    WHERE publicado = 1
    ORDER BY fecha DESC
    LIMIT :limit
    ");
  
    $x->execute([
        'limit' => $limit
    ]);

    $y = $x->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

This code works on my old projects. You can also look on PHP.net

Reference: http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php