# Why LIMIT and OFFSET does not work in mysql script?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying the following mysql script, but it says `NumOfRecords` and `Offsetpage` not defined.

```
SET @NumOfRecords = 10;
SET @Offsetpage = 0;
SET @DocumentStatus = 'PENDING';
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE DOCUMENT_VERIFICATION_STATUS = @DocumentStatus ORDER BY DOCUMENT_UPLOADED_DATE DESC LIMIT @NumOfRecords OFFSET @Offsetpage
```

Any help ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/using-variable-in-a-limit-clause-in-mysql seems to hold the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User variables in the `LIMIT` clause is not supported.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html says:

> User variables may be used in most contexts where expressions are permitted. This does not currently include contexts that explicitly require a literal value, such as in the `LIMIT` clause of a `SELECT` statement, or the `IGNORE N LINES` clause of a `LOAD DATA` statement.

In other words, you must use literal integers, or else you can use a prepared statement:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM documents WHERE DOCUMENT_VERIFICATION_STATUS = ? ORDER BY DOCUMENT_UPLOADED_DATE DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?';
EXECUTE stmt USING @DocumentStatus, @NumOfRecords, @Offsetpage;
```

You do not have to use a stored procedure for this, you can do prepared statements directly in any database session.

You can run prepared statements directly in most client APIs, without using the `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` syntax. You don't have to define user variables either.

For example, in PHP:

```
<?php

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM documents WHERE DOCUMENT_VERIFICATION_STATUS = ? ORDER BY DOCUMENT_UPLOADED_DATE DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?');
$stmt->execute( [ 'PENDING', 10, 0 ] );
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation.