# Select a portion of random rows dynamically in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hi I wondered how to select a random set of 2% of all rows.
I know that we can do it in such a way: 'LIMIT 100'.
But the challenge here is that the table size changes, but I always want 2% of total rows by random, either rounding up or down is fine.
The table has unique id for each row.
Does anyone know how to do it?

```sql
SET @size := CEILING(0.02*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders));

SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    `orders`
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT (SELECT @size)
```

I have tried using session variable, but the last line doesn't seem to work (LIMIT (SELECT @size))

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Can you use a prepared statement instead? `select * from orders order by rand() limit ?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using variable in a LIMIT clause in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/using-variable-in-a-limit-clause-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL 8+, you can use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function to give a row number to each row, then select only rows with row numbers less than the maximum row number * 0.02 (i.e. 2% of rows). For example:

```
WITH cte AS 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) AS rn
 FROM orders),
cte2 AS
(SELECT MAX(rn) AS numrows FROM cte)
SELECT *
FROM cte
JOIN cte2
WHERE rn < numrows * 0.02
```

Here's a [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79ced19766fe6096ae9a1b8c9fd697bc) using a numbers table.

In MySQL 5.x you can emulate the `ROW_NUMBER()` function using variables or a `JOIN`. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) gives good examples of how to do this.

Comment: Got it! Thank you. I am using MySQL 5.7 to accommodate Sequel Pro. A simulated ROW_NUMBER() seems to slove my questions.