# median in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to find the median value of **l** from the table **chair**:

```
set @r = (select CEIL(COUNT(*)/2) from chair);
select max(l) from chair order by lat_n limit @r;
```

Is anyone know why I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@r' at line 1

Comment: And when you checked your version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using variable in a LIMIT clause in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/using-variable-in-a-limit-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: LIMIT with dynamic parameter(s) may be used in prepared statement only, not in regular query.

Comment: For MySQL 8+ use [NTH_VALUE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_nth-value) function.

Answer (score 0):

I woudl suggest window functions.  For instance, if `l` is numeric:

```
select (case when cnt % 1 = 1
             then max(case when tile = 1 then l end)
             else (max(case when tile = 1 then l end) + min(case when tile = 2 then l end)) / 2
        end)
from (select c.*, count(*) over () as cnt,
             ntile(2) over (order by l) as tile
      from chair c
     ) c
```