# How does LIMIT accept a parameter

Tags: mysql, sql-limit

Using [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6CpUxsKHugETb7kuiY4ZvM/0), I create a table

```
create table t(x int);
insert into t values(1),(2),(3);
```

`LIMIT` works

```
select * from t limit 1,1;
```

returns `x|2`

It is [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) that user-defined variables are not allowed.

> User variables may be used in most contexts where expressions are permitted. This does not currently include contexts that explicitly require a literal value, such as in the LIMIT clause of a SELECT statement, or the IGNORE N LINES clause of a LOAD DATA statement

so

```
set @s=1;
select * from t limit @s,1;
```

produces an error:

> Query Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@s,1' at line 1

However, if I create a procedure

```
delimiter //;
create procedure lmt(s int)
begin
select * from t limit s,1;
end;

call lmt(@s);
```

it appears that parameters *are* accepted, so what is the difference between a user-variable and a procedure parameter that allows this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using variable in a LIMIT clause in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245180/using-variable-in-a-limit-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: @javdromero; not really - I got it to work, I just can't see why a procedure call is necessary.

Comment: It's this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56811  (which is still open....)